# Using Proxies to Handle HTTPS Connection Requests

Tags: python, https, proxy

I'm trying to run code on a site that only accepts HTTPS connections, and am having trouble incorporating it with proxies.

I run code such as this to instantiate the proxy:

```
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://' + proxy
```

And when I try to complete requests using said previously implemented proxy (I'm going through the site's API), I always get this error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host=[ . . . ], port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: [. . .] (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fab996ef790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)))
```

The question I have is to of course how to alleviate the error, though more primarily, when a HTTPS connection is forced, what are the ways to work around it so you're not completely stopped from utilizing or maneuvering around the site (with proxies)?

Comment: I hade the same issues and got around it by defining a SSL context, it can be done with the urllib.request and urlopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy server's host name can not be resolved to an IP address.

Either there is a problem with the proxy's host name, or there is a problem with the DNS server. If you are sure that the host is correct, try using its IP address, e.g.

```
proxy = '192.168.1.1:1234'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://' + proxy
```

If that works then the proxy is OK, but the name resolution is failing for some reason. Try using `curl` and see if that works, e.g.

```
https_proxy='https://localhost:1234' curl -v https://httpbin.org
```

Comment: Okay so I ran through those test, and they all worked except for when using `localhost:1234` and `curl`; and I've linked the information presented after running it here: http://hastebin.com/gozotepozu.vhdl

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, for the `curl` command you should replace `localhost:1234` with the hostname and port of your proxy. But it sounds like it works in Python when an IP address is specified, so you need to figure out why your hostname is not resolving to that IP address.

Comment: No yeah I did that the first time, in fact this is what I got: http://hastebin.com/bovoqajeru.xml Though then I thought about it some more, I began to suspect that maybe you were relating it to the computer's individual connection . . . anyway, I over thought it haha.

Comment: Okay I changed up some things and it's returning this @mhawke: http://hastebin.com/ikinevenoj.vhdl Thoughts?

Comment: The connection to the proxy is being refused. Double check the IP address and port. In Python I've tested using IP address:port `104.45.152.53:3128` and it works for me with `requests.get('https://httpbin.org')`. This is a valid test because your API is using `requests` which in turn is using `urllib3`. Beyond this I can offer no further advice. That proxy server is on a **lot** of blacklists.

Comment: Alright thanks I'll try it out. Yeah it's just a random public proxy, so not too surprised there.